# Event Reciever(item deleting) pop up for event cancellation yes/np sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

Is there any way that we can create a pop up on item deleting event reiever -- so when an item is deleting which gives us option whether to go ahead and delete the item or cancel the delete..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ItemDeleting runs on Server and pop ups runs as javascript on client side, so you cannot display a confirmation popup.